# SharedPreference Instance in Android per user

Tags: android, session

I'm new to Android application development. I an developing a simple login app . I'm using SharedPreferences technique for session management. I have a doubt regarding SharedPreferences instance. For ex. A user login in the app and an instance of SharedPreferences class gets generated for storing it's details in key-value pair. I want to know that if the same user called SharedPreferences class in another activity, would the same instance is allotted to him or not(before clicking the logout button).If not, how SharedPreferences class differentiates between existing user and new user. I think that SharedPreferences class uses the session id for identifying whether a session exist for that user and return the same instance each time it is called before user destroy the session. Please clarify it..

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` is returned to any caller that retrieves it using the same file name no matter where you retrieve it within your app, as long as you use the same file name for the `SharedPreferences` that one instance will be return to you everytime, so each caller using the same file name will see each other edits.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but you can use the name parameter of `getSharedPreferences` to differentiate between two shared preferences. See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html for details